# Fetch Data from table 1 based on text in a column and a different text in a column of different table

Tags: sql, apache-phoenix

I have two tables.

Table 1:

```
T1id1(pk) col1 col2 col3
```

Table 2:

```
id(pk) T1id1(FK) col1 col2 col3
```

I get two texts from user, where table1.col1 has some text(like %text1%) and similarly for table2 col1 i get another text which is not equal to text1(Like  %text2%).

I need to get a set of hundred records from table1 where table2 col1 contains text2 **AND** Table1 col1 contains text1.  When queried for next set of 100, i shouldn't get any of the records that have come in first set of 100.

Below is the sample query I have written but it is failing. I am using Apache Phoenix and solution in any of the SQL compatible DB is fine.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE T1id1 IN (select T1id1 from ndm.table1 where
T1id1 NOT IN( select T1id1 from table1 where T1id1 in (select distinct
T1id1(FK) from table2 WHERE table2.col1 like '%text2%' )LIMIT     100)     AND T1id1 in (select distinct T1id1(FK) from table2 WHERE     
table2.col1 like '%text2%' limit 200) and table1.col1 ilike '%text2%' LIMIT 100);
```

Comment: better to include sample data and expected output

Comment: You will probably need some sort order in your outer query - and continue from there. If this doesn't work for you, you might want to think about a (for this particular purpose) specific flag. In any case: Can you be sure, there won't be any concurrent updates, which would move the line between the records already displayed, and those still to be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you use `ILIKE`, you probably tried with PostgreSQL - which does seem to allow multiple `LIMIT`s in a single statement. (Judging from this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eb63/1), where -compared to your statement- **ndm.table1** was changed to **table1**, and **(FK)** dropped twice).

But even though the adjusted

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1
WHERE
  T1id1 IN
    (select
       T1id1
     from table1
     where
       T1id1 NOT IN
         (select T1id1
          from table1
          where
            T1id1 in
              (select distinct
                 T1id1
               from table2
               WHERE
                 table2.col1 like '%text2%'
              )
          LIMIT 100
         )
     AND T1id1 in
       (select distinct
          T1id1
        from table2
        WHERE
          table2.col1 like '%text2%'
        limit 200
       )
     and
     table1.col1 ilike '%text2%'
     LIMIT 100
    )
;
```

seems to be accepted by PostgreSQL - it is not likely to return the expected result:

> When using LIMIT, it is important to use an ORDER BY clause that
>   constrains the result rows into a unique order. Otherwise you will get
>   an unpredictable subset of the query's rows. You might be asking for
>   the tenth through twentieth rows, but tenth through twentieth in what
>   ordering? The ordering is unknown, unless you specified ORDER BY.

<sup>From PostgreSQL 9.3 documentation [7.6 LIMIT and OFFSET](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-limit.html).</sup>

Starting from scratch just with your problem description (and peeking for some details at your statement), something along the lines of

```
SELECT
  T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
  ON T1.t1id1 = T2.t1id1
  AND INSTR(T1.col1, 'teXT1')
  AND INSTR(T2.col1, 'teXT2')
ORDER BY T1.t1id1, T2.id
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
;

SELECT
  T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
  ON T1.t1id1 = T2.t1id1
  AND INSTR(T1.col1, 'teXT1')
  AND INSTR(T2.col1, 'teXT2')
ORDER BY T1.t1id1, T2.id
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
;

SELECT DISTINCT
  T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
  ON T1.t1id1 = T2.t1id1
  AND INSTR(T1.col1, 'teXT1')
  AND INSTR(T2.col1, 'teXT2')
ORDER BY T1.t1id1, T2.id
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
;
```

should get you into the right direction. Whether or not you need the `DISTINCT` does to some degree depend on your data - but more importantly on your overall requirements. Please compare statements 1 through 4 to 5 through 7 in below SQL Fiddle for an indication of the effect.

The main thing is to combine `LIMIT` with `OFFSET` - for which you seem to have tried to find your own replacement.

Apart from that: With the wildcards just at both ends of the strings, `INSTR` has the same selectivity as `LIKE` - but it is more efficient in some cases...

Remembering your use of `ILIKE`: Neither `LIKE` nor `INSTR` is case sensitive in MySQL as long as there is no binary string involved in the comparison.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81a5b/1).

Please comment, if and as adjustment / further detail is required.

Comment: I will try and let u know for sure tomorrow

Comment: Yes Abecee, Actually, I am using Apache Phoenix. I try to get generic SQL queries so that i can use them as reference to implement my solution so that i too learn. When I asked this query we are using 4.3.1 version of phoenix where instr function doesnt exist. But now that we upgraded to 4.5 I am able to use your suggestion and make it work . Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Well - that's why it makes sense to specify your environment. And on the other hand, feel free to use comments to supply more detail. Here, the use of `INSTR` was a matter of preference. It could easily have been replaced by, e.g., `LIKE`. See you around.